# having difficulty fetching JSON Dictionary

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, swift3, alamofire

My response from API is

```
 items are.....****************** ("user_img",     http://www.xxx/Content/Images/Products/NoImageAvailable.jpg)
  items are.....****************** ("user_posts", 10)
  items are.....****************** ("5", {
  "post_id" : 135,
  "post_img" : [
    {
   "guid" : "http:\/\/www.xxx\/wp-     content\/uploads\/2016\/10\/IMG_1477393867.jpg"
  }
]
})
items are.....****************** ("9", {
"post_id" : 143,
"post_img" : [
  {
    "guid" : "http:\/\/www.xxx\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/10\/IMG_1477453054.jpg"
}
]
})
items are.....****************** ("2", {
"post_id" : 129,
"post_img" : [
   {
    "guid" : "http:\/\/www.xxx\/wp-  content\/uploads\/2016\/10\/IMG_1477280037.jpg"
  }
  ]
 })
items are.....****************** ("1", {
 "post_id" : 112,
 "post_img" : [
   {
    "guid" : "http:\/\/www.xxx\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/10\/IMG_1475494067.jpg"
}
 ]
})
items are.....****************** ("8", {
 "post_id" : 141,
 "post_img" : [
  {
  "guid" : "http:\/\/www.xxx\/wp-   content\/uploads\/2016\/10\/IMG_1477452361.jpg"
    }
      ]
})
```

function from where I called it

```
 func getJSON(){

    let getEndPoint: String = "http://xxx/api/get_user_profile_info/"
    Alamofire.request(getEndPoint)
        .responseJSON { response in

            guard response.result.error == nil else {
                // got an error in getting the data, need to handle it
                print("error calling GET")
                print(response.result.error!)
                return
            }

            if let value = response.result.value {

                let json = JSON(value)
               // print(jsonM)
                //print("message are***********************************************")
                //print(json["message"].dictionary)
                let message = json["message"].dictionary

                for items in message! {

                    print("items are.....******************", items)


                }


                 //DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // self.afData = 1
               // self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
    }

}
```

**Model Class**

```
class ProfileJSON {

    var user_Image: URL?
    var post_image:URL?


    init(items: JSON) {

        self.user_Image = items["user_img"].URL

        let post_imgAA = items["post_img"].array
        for itemsIMG in post_imgAA! {
            self.post_image = itemsIMG["guid"].URL
        }
    }

}
```

I want to get the **user_img** to show as profile picture and the 
**post_img** for showing picture in the **CollectionViewCell** . Finding it difficult to convert **JSON** **Dictionary** to **Swift** **MutableObject** . Any suggestion , any tutorial link would be great great help for me. I have just started to work with **JSON** from this month , finding it difficult.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ProfileJSON` you need to create array of `URL` type for `post_image` because `user_Image` is once but `post_image` is coming multiple times and then you can get `post_image` from dictionary like this.

```
class ProfileJSON {

    var user_Image: URL?
    var post_image: [URL?] = [URL?]()

    init(dic: [String: Any]) {
        if let userUrl = dic["user_img"] as? String {
            self.user_Image = URL(string: userUrl)
        }

        //For getting only number keys with ascending order
        let keys = (Array(dic.keys) as [String]).filter { (Int($0) != nil) }.sorted {
            (s1, s2) -> Bool in return s1.localizedStandardCompare(s2) == .orderedAscending
        }

        //Loop through the keys Array and append all your `post_image`.
        for key in keys {                
            if let innerDic = dic[key] as? [String: Any], 
            let post_imgArray = innerDic["post_img"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                for post in post_imgArray {
                    if let postUrl = post["guid"] as? String {
                        self.post_image.append(URL(string: postUrl))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Now create the object of `ProfileJSON` after initialization of `message` like this.

```
if let message = json["message"] as? [String: Any] {
     let profileJSON = ProfileJSON(dic: message)
}
```

Comment: it will take some time for me to digest haha , but thank you so much for your help. You are a Legend .

Comment: @ArafinMacRussell Welcome mate:)

Answer (score 1):

You can extract details from dictionary using DicitonaryObject.objectForKey("KEYNAME") as? Datatype .
Datatype would the of the value stored in that key.
Store it in a variable and use it wherever you want.